# Octlet, quad word or what?

Tags: c++, c, types

I am translating some documentation on libraw1394 to Russian. The documentation on libraw1394 says:

> The basic data structures defined in
>   the standard and used in this document
>   are the quadlet (32 bit quantity) and
>   the **octlet** (64 bit quantity)...

There is no such unit like "octlet" in Russian. I used to use "quad word" (russian "chetvertnoye slovo") for 64 bit quantity. Would it be correct to substitute "octlet" by "quad word"?

What are the alternative terms for "octlet"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

octlet == 8-byte   [8-байт ?]

I wouldn't use "WORD" because a word can vary. It could be 1 byte, 2 bytes, 4 bytes...  a Byte is always 8 bits.

Answer (score 4):

I've never heard of an "octlet" before. Can't you just translate "64-bit quantity" literally? I find "quad word" confusing as well, as on a native 64-bit platform, a "word" could be considered to be 64 bits as well. In fact, this whole definition of a "word" seems to go back to the bad old days of 16-bit computing.

Comment: I too have never heard of octlet. I would not add another number into the mix in your replacement name for it. 8 bytes leads to octlet. 64 bits is ok. But 4 words requires you to know that a word is 2 bytes, which it isn't always, and hides the 8-ness or 64-ness of the original term.

Comment: "Octlet" is also easily mistaken for "octet", a synonym for (8-bit) byte used in IETF documents such as RFCs. I don't know if it exists with the same usage in Russian.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science), one could use "doubleword" or "quadword" for 64bit integers, yet "quadword" can also be used for 128bit integers and "doubleword" for 32bit ones.

The problem is the term "word", which actually means a "fixed sized group of bits that are handled together by the system" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computing) ).

In Intel's documentation on its own processors:

- "word" means "16bit integers",
- "double word" means "32bit integers",
- "quad word" means "64bit integers",
- "double quad word" means "128bit integers".

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the english terms directly, perhaps quartet (квартет) and octet (Октет) will do...

However, to avoid confusion with 8-bit octets, it might be better to make up less ambiguous words, eg кварто байт and октябристов(???) байт; perhaps a native speaker could tell us if these terms make any sense, because I'm not really convinced that Google is right with its suggestion for the second term...

Comment: These are very strongly associated with groups of musicians and might therefore be confusing.

Comment: Moreover, there is a strong association of octet = 8 bits.  Especially in SMTP RFCs

Comment: @T33C, Alexander: added some new suggestions, which might (or might not) make any sense at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with specifying the number of bits? When I need this type of precision, I usually just refer to the number of bits used, i.e. 32-bit integer or 64-bit integer. For shorter, more pronounceable, names just tack on the bit specifier after the type, such as int32/int64 (which is something I often say but rarely write).

I am not sure of the idiomatic way to express this in Russian though, that will be up to you to decide :-)